# how to clone an external git repository for personal dashboard on kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to create a personal dashboard on kubernetes, am trying to create to clone an external repository from git, but, am getting this error,
error: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 378: mapping values are not allowed in this context

now if you want to have a kubernet dashboard than you have to type 
kubectl create -f https://rawgit.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml

is it possible to replace kubernetes dashboard by our own dashboard by cloning an external git repository?

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to replace kubernetes dashboard by our own dashboard by cloning an external git repository?

Yes, most certainly it is.

You have to pay attention to few things:

- Cloning repository from [Dashboard Git](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard) (`git clone https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard.git`) and then simply running `src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml` included within won't help you. [Mentioned manifest file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml) uses pregenerated image (at this moment it is `image: k8s.gcr.io/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64:v1.8.3`). If you simply run it from local repository you'll pull external image which is not your desire...
- You have to make changes and then (with included Dockerfile) you need to build target `kubernetes-dashboard` image. Finally you have to reference such an image in your local `kubernetes-dashboard.yaml` file in order to incorporate your changes. You can do it with local docker repository or external, public or private, name your poison...

You are advised to check [developer getting started](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Getting-started) reference from repository for more details, especially related to installation of prerequisites and running of tests.